# Reference element from Json array

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to select a certain element which is included in the response I get from an API. The "problem" is that this json is already within a ForEach activity, as I need to use that in order to obtain this values from my previous Web Activity. So I cannot use another ForEach activity inside of it.

My question/Ask is how to get the **machineId** element in order to use in another webactivity. Any suggestion is appreciated!

This is how my JSON looks like:

```
"grouping": {
        "branchNodes": [
            {
                "type": "COUNTER",
                "machineId": 267315,
                "category": "CH9934787828372398 SUFT",
                "subgroup": {
                    "first": {
                        "href": "https://api.XXXXX.com/c/branch/COUNTER/267315"
                    },
                    "second": {
                        "href": "https://api.XXXXX.com/c/branch/COUNTER/267315/children"
                    },
                    "third": {
                        "href": "https://api.XXXXX.com/c/branch/267315"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Pipeline:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNsYJ.png)

I want to select the value from **machineId**

Thank you!

I have tried doing this with an Execute Pipeline activity but I do not know how to reference the first activity in my ForEach which is generating the above json.

Comment: can you add pipeline image to get better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to get the **machineId** element in order to use in another webactivity.

As you said you are getting Json from first web activity and need `machine Id` from it to use it further

- I tried and getting the similar output from First web activity as below:
  [image]
- Now we will create another pipeline to proceed with `machine Id` with pipeline parameter as type object.
  [image]
- Now we will refer this to another pipeline which have pipeline parameter as type object created from execute pipeline with value `@activity('Web1').output.grouping`.
  [image]
- In this pipeline we will take ForEach activity with items as `@pipeline().parameters.previouspipelinevalue.branchNodes`
  [image]
- Under this foreach activity you will get the **machine Id** by `@item().machineId` this value you can use or refer it for further use[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pratik! Is there another possible approach besides the ExecutePipeline? Could I instead use a second ForEach after the First FE? 
The reason for that is to prevent creating yet another pipeline. 
Also how can I see the output of machineId (it's not in the output of the Child Pipeline)?

Comment: You can't use nested foreach loop in ADF Because of it you will need two level pipeline in child pipeline you can create a pipeline return value to get machine id as output in pipeline.